# After upgrading Ubuntu, dates from MSSQL are returned in a fancy format

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, ubuntu, pdo

I have recently updated my dev machine to the latest (still in beta) ubuntu version. Almost everything works as espected but I am facing a little strange thing with dates.

I have this query (it's only an example, as it happens with every query containing dates)

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
ORDER BY created DESC
```

The exact same query gives this result on the production server: `2016-10-01`. On my dev machine, with the "old" ubuntu version it gives the same result, while on with the new ubuntu version I obtain this: `Oct 1 2016 12:00:00:AM`.

What I mean is that if I do a `print_r($queryResults)` immediately after the query I obtain those different date format.

I guess it's a different configuration on PHP, but what should I look at?

I am using PHP7.1 installed from this repository: `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php`

Edit: might be worth adding that I am using PDO to connect to SQL Server and do all of the queries...

Comment: which format does `mysql` returns when you run the above `query` directly on `mysql`?

Comment: It returns `2016-10-01`. It's MSSQL though

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this by creating the file `/etc/freetds/locales.conf` and adding add these two lines:

```
[default]
date format = %Y-%m-%d
```

Save, reboot, enjoy!